# Get instance of repository interface in Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel (version 8.x) for a project. I'm struggling to get an instance of my repository interface. I assume it is possible to get an instance of a repository interface, but actually I did not get it to work.

Here is my code:
I have a standard migration created with

`$ php artisan make:migration copy_guests_landing_page_db_entries_from_landing_page1`

So this is the migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CopyGuestsLandingPageDbEntriesFromLandingPage1 extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Nothing special yet.
Now I have a repository and an implementation configured. Here are the classes.

**Repository interface:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Guest;

interface GuestLandingPageRepository
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     * 
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage
     */
    public function findOrFail($id);

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * 
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage
     */
    public function create($data = []);

    /**
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage[]
     */
    public function all();

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function count();

    /**
     * Get guest by identifier token
     * @param string $token 
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage
     */
    public function getByIdentifierToken($token);

    /**
     * Get guest by identifier token
     * @param int $guestId 
     * @param int $landingPageId 
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage
     */
    public function getByGuestIdAndLandingPageId($guestId,$landingPageId);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Guest;

class GuestLandingPageRepositoryImpl extends \App\Repositories\BaseRepository implements \App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPageRepository {
    public function __construct(\App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage $guestLandingPage) {
        parent::__construct($guestLandingPage);
    }

    /**
     * Get guest by identifier token
     * @param string $token 
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage
     */
    public function getByIdentifierToken($token) {
        return $this->model->where('identifier_token', $token)->get()->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get guest by identifier token
     * @param int $guestId 
     * @param int $landingPageId 
     * @return \App\Models\Guest\GuestLandingPage
     */
    public function getByGuestIdAndLandingPageId($guestId,$landingPageId) {
        return $this->model->where('guest_id', $guestId)->where('landing_page_id',$landingPageId)->get()->first();
    }
}
```

I also registered it in the `RepositoriesServiceProviders` class (in the `register` method).

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class RepositoriesServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    public function register() {
        ....
        //GuestLandingPage
        $this->app->bind(\App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPageRepository::class, \App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPageRepositoryImpl::class);
        ...
    }
}
```

...and added this `RepositoriesServiceProviders` class in the `config\app.php`.
So everything fine configured and tested. If I use this interface in an controller class, I get the implementation of the interface. So far, so good.

But how can I manage to use this in a migration. I'm sure this is simple, but I actually did not get it to work. If I try to use...

```
$this->app->make('App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPage');
```

...in the `up()` method of the migration, I get an error, that the class cannot be instantiated.

> Target [\App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPageRepository] is not
> instantiable.

Is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: `$guestLandingPage = resolve('App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPage');`

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand Thanks for your hint, but still the same error `Target [\App\Repositories\Guest\GuestLandingPageRepository] is not instantiable.`